# Display Images From A Folder (slideshow)

Tags: php, image, directory, slideshow

I have been trying to google and find out how to make a .php script that will make a an automatic slideshow of images from a folder, I've only managed to get the pictures to automatically show up on the php page, but I can't figure out how to make them slide one by one, like a slideshow.

[Here](http://iseeit.no/page/autopic/index.php) is the url to the page where the images show up, so you can have a look
Here is the code I've used.

```
<?
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image" />'."<br><br>";
}
?>
```

Do you know how to make this happen? Or another way to do it? easier way?
Java/XML?

Comment: Try learning some javascript ^_^ it might help you out **alot** :-)

Answer (score 1):

To affect the client side, you'll need to use JavaScript. PHP only echos out static content on the server.

[Here is a list of options you *could* use](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/top-10-javascript-slideshows-carousels-and-sliders)

Comment: @Remi use javascript (or if you want to look into a library like jQuery you can)

Comment: I've heard about jQuery, but I have a no idea of where to start looking.

Comment: @Remi right here on stackoverflow or just search on google :-)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that tomorrow :)