# Display Images From A Folder (slideshow) from external folder / URL

Tags: php

**I have the code below**

```
<?php
$directory = 'images/slideshow';    
try {       
    // Styling for images   
    echo '<div id="myslides">'; 
    foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {            
        if ($item->isFile()) {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $item;   
            echo '<img src="' . $path . '"/>';  
        }
    }   
    echo '</div>';
}   
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'No images found for this slideshow.<br />';   
}
?>
```

copied from this topic:
[Display Images From A Folder (slideshow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484018/display-images-from-a-folder-slideshow)

I would like to know if its possible to load the images externally instead, or from a specific directory of a URL? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you would need to know the urls of each photo. Though that would be easy if you can make them follow a certain pattern I.e. www.example.com/dir/photo1, www.example.com/dir/photo2.

The external server you point must allow remote linking as well.

Then it's just a matter of making the links:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < NUMBER_OF_PHOTOS; ++$i) {
    echo '<img src="http://www.example.com/dir/photo'.$i.'"/>';
}
```

Comment: does it mean it wont load the images of the external images anymore, like the script above?

Comment: does it mean it wont load the images in the external folder anymore, like the script above?